# Error encoding with Huffman in Matlab

Tags: matlab, huffman-code

I have a file where i can read the next example of characters:

```
HP†d€H EPŠ€E iEPƒ1€E OGP†d€G HP†d€H JP†d€J LP†d€L.......
```

And when I try to encode the samples of the file using the function of Matlab "huffmanenco" Matlab says me this:

```
Error using huffmanenco (line 86)
The Huffman dictionary provided does not have the codes for all the input
signals.

Error in RETO2 (line 35)
enco=huffmanenco(double(x),dict);
```

The next code is the one I'm using:

```
fileID = fopen('reto2014.mid');
[x,cont]=fscanf(fileID,'%c');
fclose(fileID);

y=[1:256];
va = hist(double(x),y);
prob= va./cont;
bar(y,prob)

[dict,avglen]=huffmandict(y,prob);
enco=huffmanenco(double(x),dict);
```

I have tried to change the variable "y" but that doesn't work or it says me that The Maximum recursion limit of 500 have been reached what can I do to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You create a dictionary for the values 1 to 256, but your text has characters with larger number representations. Using the characters you posted, you find that the minimum is 32 and the maximum is 8364. You have to create a dictionary containing all possible characters:

```
y = double(unique(x));
```

This should give the desired results. You could also use

```
y = 1:65535;
```

which will probably give you exactly the same result, as for all characters which you don't have in your text `x`, the probability is 0.

Comment: Ok that worked fine, I had a File with 22973 bytes and after encoding with Huffman I have a result of 800 bytes is it a correct result or it is monstrous? (I have tried encoding with Winrar and it gives me 2100 bytes)